# how to get attachments from particular post id in wordpress

Tags: wordpress

```
$argsThumb = array(
    'order'          => 'ASC',
    'post_type'      => 'attachment',
    'post_parent'    => $post->ID,
    'post_mime_type' => 'image',
    'post_status'    => null
);
$attachments = get_posts($argsThumb);
if ($attachments) {
    foreach ($attachments as $attachment) { ?>

    <div class="item">
        <a href="<?php wp_get_attachment_url($attachment->ID, 'large', false, false); ?>" class="zoom" rel="group">
            <span class="thumb">
                <img class="small" src="<?php wp_get_attachment_url($attachment->ID, 'medium', false, false); ?>" />
            </span>
        </a> 

    </div>

<?php } } ?>
```

Comment: What's the question? Your code snippet doesn't work? Are there errors? Does it return anything?

Answer (score 1):

[`wp_get_attachment_url`](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_get_attachment_url) takes only one parameter + you need to echo:

`<?php echo wp_get_attachment_url( $attachment->ID ); ?>`

Note: to get specific image sizes, use [`wp_get_attachment_image_src`](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_get_attachment_image_src)

Comment: but attachment images are showed ,problem is all media image files are showed. I want only with in that post